AppInsights - Summarize by count() show result in grid even if 0
Hello I have a query like this:
customEvents
| where name in ("event1", "event2")
| summarize count() by name

And the thing is that when event2 has no results in the timerange it just shows event1 - x and no more rows.
I want it to show the result for both events regardless of the result so the grid always show the sane number of rows.
Thanks.

Can you try this customEvents | where name in ("event1", "event2") | summarize count() by name | union (customEvents | where name in ("event1") | summarize count() by name) | project name, count_

I am not sure if this is the most elegant solution but at least serves my purpose (as I can organize the query a bit better):
let event1 = customEvents
| where name == "event1"
| summarize count()
|extend newname = "event1";

let event2 = customEvents
| where name == "event2"
| summarize count()
|extend newname = "event2";

union event1 , event2 
| project newname, count_

This worked like a charm!
